# Flask / SQLAlchemy - unable to query relationship properly

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following code in Flask. I want users to be able to follow specified RSS feeds, which is saved in the 'relationships_feed' table but I'm unable to get this outputting correctly.

**Models**

```
class Relationships_Feed(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'relationships_feed'
    feed_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('feeds.id'), primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), primary_key=True)


class Feed(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'feeds'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    feed_url = db.Column(db.String(255), index=False, unique=True)
    feed_name = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True)

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    confirmed = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    role_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('roles.id'))
    feeds = db.relationship('Feed', secondary='relationships_feed', backref='user', lazy='dynamic')
```

Here is how I'm calling the code whilst troubleshooting the issue.

The expected outcome is that **user.feeds** returns all feeds he is subscribed to, based on the data in the **relationships_feed** table.

**Calling code**

```
users = db.session.query(User)

for user in users:
    print (user.first_name)
    print (user.last_name)
    print (user.email)
    print (user.feeds)
```

**Output** (fake data in db)

```
11:21:40 web.1    | Robert
11:21:40 web.1    | Williams
11:21:40 web.1    | svelazquez@jones.org
11:21:40 web.1    | SELECT feeds.id AS feeds_id, feeds.feed_url AS feeds_feed_url, feeds.feed_name AS feeds_feed_name
11:21:40 web.1    | FROM feeds, relationships_feed
11:21:40 web.1    | WHERE ? = relationships_feed.user_id AND feeds.id = relationships_feed.feed_id
```

All I receive back is the raw query itself, which makes me think I'm not querying it correctly but I've been through multiple guides and documentation and still unable to resolve. Is this a simple fix I'm missing?

Comment: you need to iterate over `user.feeds`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You need to call `.all()` on a lazy relationship

```
feeds = db.relationship('Feed', secondary='relationships_feed', backref='user', lazy='dynamic')
```

In your model, you made this relationship lazy, which means that on accessing `feeds` property, it will not get all items but you have to explicitly get all those items either by calling `user.feeds.all()` or use it like iterator.

```
for feed in user.feeds:
    print(feed)
```

You can get all feeds at once

```
feeds = user.feeds.all()
```

In you scenario,

```
for user in users:
    print (user.first_name)
    print (user.last_name)
    print (user.email)
    print (user.feeds.all()
```